# How do I upload multiple files to Azure blob storage using an ID parameter as a container?

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, azure-blob-storage

I've created a storage account on Azure for uploading files to.  I am using KenoUI Async upload widget which allows multiple file uploads.  What I'd like to do is have the system create a container based on the passing in `Id` parameter if it doesn't already exist.

I'm struggling with the actual upload part however, I'm not sure how to pass the enumerable files to the storage account.  Here is my code so far:

```
public ActionResult Async_Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string id)
    {
        //Connect to Azure
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("my_AzureStorageConnectionString"));

        //Create Blob Client
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        //Retrieve a reference to a container
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("vehicle_" + id);

        try
        {
            // Create the container if it doesn't already exist
            blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);

        }
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            //This doesn't seem right to me and it's where I'm struggling
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var physicalPath = Path.Combine(blobContainer, fileName);
            file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
        }

        // Return an empty string to signify success
        return Content("");
    }
```

What I've attempted to do is create a method that connects to my Azure storage account and:

1. Check for the existence of a container with the same ID as the
   the parameter that's passed in, if it doesn't exist, create it.
2. Upload the files to the existing or newly created directory and give them a prefix of the ID i.e. "_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gaurav Mantri said above, we will need to use Azure Storage SDK.

For better performance, we can do as below:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>

{

    CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName); 

    blob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);

    file.InputStream.Close();


});
```

Your code will be better as below:

```
public ActionResult Async_Save(List<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string id)

{

// Connect to Azure

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("my_AzureStorageConnectionString"));

try

{

   //Create Blob Client

   CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

   //Retrieve a reference to a container

   CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("vehicle_" + id);

   // Create the container if it doesn't already exist

   blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

   Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>

   {

       CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);

       blob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);

       file.InputStream.Close();

   });

}

catch (Exception ex)

{

    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);

} 

// Return an empty string to signify success

    return new ContentResult();

}
```

More information about how to use Azure Storage SDK, we can refer to:

[Get Quick Start with Storage SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=windows)

Comment: Thank you for this example.  I have tried to implement it into my solution but problems arise at line `blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();` and the method ends.  There is an error in the console of `XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: https://localhost:44354/Storage/Async_Save
Line Number 1, Column 1:`.  I used a try/catch to see what the problem was and it shows `Error400 Bad Request`.  Could this be a permissions issue since it's the exact point it should make a container?

Comment: I found the problem, the 400 bad request has a description of `invalid characters used`  If you look at Azure the naming must be a number or a letter or a dash but start with a letter, so `vehicle_` becomes `vehicle-`.

Comment: Yes, we should enter the valid name of the container.

Comment: @Yanayaya If the issue was resolved, you can mark the helpful post as answer to help other community members find the helpful information quickly.

Answer (score 2):

To upload a blob in Azure Storage, you will need to use Azure Storage SDK.

Please replace the following code:

```
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        //This doesn't seem right to me and it's where I'm struggling
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var physicalPath = Path.Combine(blobContainer, fileName);
        file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
    }
```

With something like:

```
  foreach (var file in files)
  {
      var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);
      using (var s = file.InputStream)
      {
          blob.UploadFromStream(s);
      }
  }
```