# Upload multiple files to Azure Blob storage using container's SAS token/URL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, shared-access-signatures

I am able to generate the SAS token for single file using this code in C#

```
BlobClient blobClient = this.container.GetBlobClient(blobPath);
BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
{
    BlobName = blobClient.Name,
    BlobContainerName = this.container.Name,
    Resource = "c", // b for blob, c for container
    StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
    ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(this.sasTokenExpiryHours),
};
sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Write);
Uri sasUri = blobClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);
return sasUri.AbsoluteUri;
```

Using the token generated, I simply send a PUT request with binary body. It works fine for single file.

Is there any way I can generate the SAS token for container and upload multiple files using the container SAS token before the token expires?

Comment: The token should work multiple times.  I think the issue is how you are sending multiple files.  Are you using one request or multiple requests?  See if following helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470941/how-do-i-upload-multiple-files-to-azure-blob-storage-using-an-id-parameter-as-a

Comment: Here, I tried to generate a URL for test.pdf.
No matter what ever I upload to this URL, a single test.pdf is created into blob storage.

`http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/localstoragecontainer/test.pdf?sv=2021-06-08&st=2022-12-26T10%3A16%3A17Z&se=2022-12-26T11%3A16%3A17Z&sr=b&sp=w&sig=epGLkXlph6PjcswNkmsHEuL1RofRcnj7UHwE%2B84Jd8A%3D`

This URL is for only test.pdf
I wanted a container URL where I can add multiple files.

The link you mentioned is using code to upload, I wanted a URL where a file can be posted simply using URL.

Comment: You would need to create a SAS URL for the blob container and then inject blob name in that SAS URL. Only then you will be able to upload multiple files. Currently you are creating a SAS URL for a single blob.

Comment: So now I have to inject blob name and create new URL for each URL like this?
`http://{the URL}/file1?{theSASToken}

http://{the URL}/file2?{theSASToken}`

Or is there simpler way?

Comment: `So now I have to inject blob name and create new URL for each URL like this? http://{the URL}/file1?{theSASToken}  http://{the URL}/file2?{theSASToken}` - That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @GauravMantri's suggestion,

```
BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
{
    BlobContainerName = this.container.Name,
    Resource = "c", // b for blob, c for container
    StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
    ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2),
};
sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Write);
Uri sasUri = this.container.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);
return sasUri.AbsoluteUri;
```

This gives the SAS token `[http://{the URL}/{theSASToken}]` and simply needed to update the URL as `http://{the URL}/file1?{theSASToken}`